# Goldfish constantly gulping but not eating

Tags: aquarium, fish, freshwater, goldfish

We are in the middle of a first time fish-in cycle (an aquarium gift from a well-meaning grandparent). We have a 2 inch Comet goldfish, who has been surviving the ordeal like a champ... until today. Today, it hasn't eaten and is constantly opening and closing its mouth. It's not spending more time than usual at the surface, no obvious spots.

Current water parameters: pH 6.4, ammonia 0ppm, nitrite 1ppm, nitrate 5ppm. Daily dose (or 2x dose) of Seachem Prime. I had been doing daily water changes to manage ammonia levels while we waited for the cycle to start, but now it's started, I only do a water change if the nitrites get over 2ppm (and rely on Prime otherwise).

The pH dropped to below 6 late last week, so I adjusted by doing a partial water change with a small amount of bicarb soda dissolved in the change water to increase the overall pH by 0.4.

Any thoughts on what might be causing the gulping and loss of appetite? What steps should I take next?

Comment: Did the temperature suddenly changes? Do you use a filter system or water changes only? Do the fish not eat, when you give food to the water? What size is the tank? Do plants are part of the tank? More than this one fish?

Answer (score 2):

Is you ammonia test kit, testing only NH4 or is it a combo test that is NH4/NH3+? How long has the tank been going?

But at a ph of close to 6, weird things happen and your ammonia readings become virtually irrelevant. When you add bicarb, even increasing the ph from 6 to 6.5, the ammonium which is not apparent on many test kits, can almost instantly become toxic even though you are measuring zero. But you're in a range of ph that few aquarists ever deal with, the ammonium / ammonia / ph relationship acts really weird at these low ph levels and minor ph upswings such as during a water change or deliberately adding something to increase ph, can cause toxic conditions even when your test kit is telling you otherwise.

What is the ph out of your tap water? This is honestly so low, you're almost making ceviche out of your comet goldfish irrespective of the ammonia in the tank...

Comment: +1 it’s probably the pH. If the worst has happened, consider looking for some "coral gravel" for the tank. I don’t know if you’ll still get it easily but it acts as a buffer and is helpful if you’re in a soft water area.